# PHP switch statement always pick default or random case when using array

Tags: php, string, post, switch-statement, hex

I'm using switch to read value with specific key from an array. the array have 2 kind of value, int (0-9) and hex (0-e). when i try to read the int, my switch always run default. when i try to return said data, it return 1 and i have case 1 but the switch run default instead.

i have tried changing to if-else with 0 error but still not working. i tried to force it to string using (string)$paramapi and change the case value to case '1' and still not working. i also have try to pass it to integer with (integer)$paramapi and (int)$paramapi while case 1 and still not working correctly.

please note that my swich variable is untouched on every ...

```
    $paramapi = trim($parraya[1]);
    $paramid = trim($parraya[2]);
    $param1 = trim($parraya[3]);
    ...
    $paramapi=settype($paramapi,"string");
        switch($paramapi){
            case '1':
                $param1 = $param1."%";
                $db = new DbOperation();
                $result = $db->addLogin(
                    $paramid,
                    $param1
                );
                if($result){
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'login success';
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true; 
                    $response['message'] = 'login failed';
                }
            break;
            case '2':
            ...         
            break;

            case '3':
            ...
            break;

            case '4':
            ...
            break;

            case '5':
            ...
            break;

            case '6':
            ...
            break;

            case '7':
            ...
            break;

            default:
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call'.' '.$aparraya[1];    
    }
```

i got "Invalid API Call 1" and want to get "login success" or "login failed"

i change `$paramapi=settype($paramapi,"string");` to `settype($paramapi,"string");` this fix some new error which i found when forcing my value to string.
i also change

```
default:
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call'.' '.$aparraya[1];    
}
```

to

```
default:
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call'.' '.$paramapi;    
}
```

and still got "invalid API call 1"

my code works now. turn out my error is because i forgot to **save** it.

Comment: `var_dump($paramapi);`, what is it?

Comment: Using an IDE like Visual Studio Code, could you possibly debug and confirm the data inside $paramapi?

Comment: And get rid of the `settype`.

Comment: After `$paramapi=settype($paramapi,"string");` try `var_dump($paramapi);` and `gettype($paramapi);`, can you edit your question with the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `settype` returns a boolean, so `$paramapi` will always be `true` or `false`. You do not need to put the result of `settype` back into `$paramapi`. It does that for you by just calling the function.

So change `$paramapi=settype($paramapi,"string");` into `settype($paramapi,"string");` and it should work.

(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)

Comment: this is technically the correct answer, as I forget to save my PHP after edit. and your answer made my switch works. thx.